# Where does presto store kafka data when using presto's kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, presto

I'm searching for a document about presto's kafka connector that mentions more about the internal and how the connector is implemented, for example, does presto store data from kafka in memory or persist to disk in a format.

The official document only contains step-by-step guide
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/kafka-tutorial.html

Does anyone have the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Internal implementation is not documented.

Regarding persistence - the connector does not store anything and it reads the Kafka topics in full every time a query is run (unless there is a query predicate allowing to limit the reading).

If you have more questions about how things are implemented in Presto, I can recommend the `#dev` channel on [Presto Community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).

Comment: What about consumer group offsets?

Comment: in full I would assume reading the offsets from earliest, and store the data in memory